# Database Crawling in GSA

Tags: google-search-appliance

I could see there are two ways to index a database records in GSA.

1. Content Sources > Databases
2. Using DB connector

As per my understanding, **Content Sources > Databases** does not support automatic recrawl. We have to manually sync after any changes occured in DB records. Is that correct?

Also, Would using [DB connectors](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/connectors/260/connector_admin/database_connector?hl=en) help in automatic recrawl?
I would like to check DB in every 15 minutes for the changes and update the index accordingly. Please suggest the viable apporach to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Content Sources > Databases approach is good for data that doesn't change often where a manual sync is acceptable. That said though, it's easy enough to write a simple client that logs in to the admin console and hits the 'Sync' link periodically.

However, if you want frequent updates like every 15m I'd definitely go with the 4.x plexi-based adaptor, not because it's newer but because it's better. Older versions of the 3.x connector were a bit flaky (although the most recent versions are much better).

What flavour DB are you looking to index?

Comment: Thanks for the information BigMikeW. I am looking for Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that Content Sources > Databases does not support any sort of automated recrawl.

Using either the 3.x Connector or 4.x Adaptor for Databases supports automatic recrawls.  If you are looking to index the rows of databases only and not using it to feed a list of URLs to index then I would go with the 4.x Database Adaptor as it is new.